# Is possible insert a Java view that extends Framelayout in composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

Is possible to insert a Java view that extends a Framelayout inside of a composable component. That I want to achieve is insert an old view component in a compose view.

I was searching but did not find any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `AndroidView`, check out more in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)